# getting updated variable value from function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this as simple as I could

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div id="outsideCounter"><p></p></div>

    <div id="clickToAdd"><p>Click me</p></div>

    <div id="insideCounter"><p></p></div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var level = 1; // start the counting at 1

    $('#outsideCounter > p').html(level); // show value of the first counter


        $('#clickToAdd').click(function(){ 

            level++; // I want this to add both counters, not just the insideCounter

            $('#insideCounter > p').html(level); // show value of the second counter
        });

});
```

Now the problem is that when you click 'clickToAdd' it adds 1 only to the **insideCounter**. How could I get that same updated level to the **outsideCounter**? I've been struggling with this for hours now and my brains are so jammed I can't figure this out on my own.

I have been exercising javascript only for a week now so please try to keep it as simple as possible because I couldn't even find anything useful from the previous answers about 'getting variable from function'.

I made [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7k4f3dux/) if that helps to understand my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can separate the selectors by a comma `,` but since both ids end with `Counter`, you could just make use of that pattern, by combining *ends-with* which works with attribute selector.

```
$('[id$=Counter] > p').html(level);
```

Comment: this will remove the <p> tags!

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `outsideCounter > p` to your selector:

```
$('#insideCounter > p, #outsideCounter > p').html(level);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7k4f3dux/4/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var level = 1; // start the counting at 1

    $('#outsideCounter > p').html(level); // show value of the first counter


        $('#clickToAdd').click(function(){ 

            level++; // I want this to add both counters, not just the insideCounter 

            $('#insideCounter > p, #outsideCounter > p').html(level); // show value of the second counter
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var level = 1; // same variable for both counter

$('#outsideCounter > p').html(level); // show first counter

$('#clickToAdd').click(function () {
    level++; // this only adds insideCounter
    $('#insideCounter > p, #outsideCounter > p').html(level);
  }); 
});
```